# Can I create an auto fill function in Laravel Inertia Js + React Js

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

**I want to make a select option where when I select no_plate then the input below is like a model and others are filled in, but after searching on Google or YouTube it doesn't work**

```
export default function CreateExitsCustomer({ datas }) {
    const [notify, setNotify] = useState(false);
    const { data, setData, processing, post, errors, register, watch } = useForm({
        no_plate: "",
        model: "",
        last_service_date: "",
        service_date: "",
        owner: "",
        mobile_phone: "",
        birthday: "",
        description: "",
    });
```

I made this in Laravel Project with Inertia JS And React JS

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.